# how to remove file extension for display, but retaining extension for href?

Tags: php, directory-listing

I'm displaying all file from a folder, that part works fine. However, Each link displays the file extension. I have tried removing it, but seems to remove the file name too. I need to display the name of the file without extension, but use a variable with the extension for the `href` of the link.

Attempt:

```
<?php

$info = pathinfo($filename);
$name = $info['filename'];
$ext  = $info['extension'];

$name = pathinfo($filename)['filename'];

$dir = opendir('folder/'); 
while ($read = readdir($dir)) 
{

if ($read!='.' && $read!='..') 
{ 
echo '<li><a class="" href="folder/'.$read.'">'.$name.'</a></li>'; 
}

}

closedir($dir); 

?>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Why would one want to do that? A file name by itself is a very unreliable and arbitrary identification of a file anyway. Shortening it and removing information certainly does not improve that issue. From a users point of view a file name should be irrelevant anyway, it is the _title_ of a file that makes sense. Apart from that: please note that there may be files without or with multiple extensions. What is usually referred to as "file name extension" actually is just a part of the file name which happens to be noted in a certain way. It has no special meaning from a technical point of view.

Comment: I don't get it...are you trying to also generate a file directory as HTML output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

easier way to do this using PHP's ScanDir

http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

```
$files =  array_diff(scandir('folder/'), array('.', '..'));

foreach($files as $file){

    $name = strstr($file, '.', TRUE);
    echo '<li><a class="" href="folder/'.$file.'">'.$name.'</a></li>';

}
```

Comment: only problem with that is it displays links to the parent directory.

Comment: Fixed that problem.

Comment: echo '<li><a class="" href="./folder/'.$file.'">'.$name.'</a></li>';

Comment: It's doing something strange, I have one file in the directory, displays one link with a file name, and then two empty links one to the root directory and another to the folder/ directory.

Comment: It shouldn't be doing that, with the array_diff in there. Make sure you tried what I put in after the edit?

Comment: Thanks so much for the help

Comment: No problem, Cheers!